# What happens when a long TCP segment is sent?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I uploaded a txt file to a server and captured the upload with Wireshark.
The issue is that there is a segment that is extreamly long and right after that i get ack's from the server for lower sequences than i should.
on line 865 my PC sends a segment with the length of 12240.
I should get an ack that is bigger than 12240 and yet this is not the case.

[Wireshark capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5IIZ.png)

Comment: https://www.networkdatapedia.com/post/2016/08/11/analyzing-tcp-segmentation-offload-tso-with-wireshark

Answer (score 1):

Look at frame 862.  The host 128.119.245.12 is advertising an MSS of 1360 bytes.  So, the maximum size of TCP segment sent by 10.0.0.12 will only contain at most 1360 bytes, despite what is being shown by Wireshark. The reason for the seemingly larger TCP segments - 12240 and 2720 bytes - is because the capture engine is receiving the packets ***before*** they are segmented by the NIC.  If you were capturing the traffic on an external device, such as from a SPAN port or via a TAP, you wouldn't see that 12240 byte segment, but rather you'd see 9 1360 byte segments sent instead.  So, this is the reason why the receiving host's ACK number doesn't match the 12240; it ACKs each 1360 byte segment it receives instead.  It isn't until frame 930 that all 9 1360 byte segments comprising the apparent 12240 segment are all acknowledged, and you can easily calculate all of this with some SEQ/ACK analysis.

Here are the SEQ #'s for host 10.0.0.12 along with the ACK #'s from host 128.119.245.12, and I've included the breakdown of the 9 1360 byte segments in brackets, `[]`, that would have actually been seen on the wire had Wireshark been run on an external machine instead of on the 10.0.0.12 host:

```
Frame #    10.0.0.12          128.119.245.12        Comments
           SEQ     Len        ACK
-------    -----------        --------------        -----------------------------
822        0       0           
862                           1                     Next expected SEQ # is now 1
863        1       0           
864        1       716                              
865        717     12240                            SEQ: 1 + 716 = 717
[865-1     2077    1360                             SEQ: 717 + 1360 = 2077]
[865-2     3437    1360                             SEQ: 2077 + 1360 = 3437]
[865-3     4797    1360                             SEQ: 3437 + 1360 = 4797]
[865-4     6157    1360                             SEQ: 4797 + 1360 = 6157]
[865-5     7517    1360                             SEQ: 6157 + 1360 = 7517]
[865-6     8877    1360                             SEQ: 7517 + 1360 = 8877]
[865-7     10237   1360                             SEQ: 8877 + 1360 = 10237]
[865-8     11597   1360                             SEQ: 10237 + 1360 = 11597]
[865-9     12957   1360                             SEQ: 11597 + 1360 = 12957]
905                           717                   ACK: The ACK to frame 864
906        12957   1360                             SEQ: 717 + 12240 = 12957
907                           2077                  ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-1
908        14317   2720                             SEQ: 12957 + 1360 = 14317
912                           3437                  ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-2
913        17037   2720                             SEQ: 14317 + 2720 = 17037
915                           4797                  ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-3
916        19757   2720                             SEQ: 17037 + 2720 = 19757
917                           6157                  ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-4
918        22477   2720                             SEQ: 19757 + 2720 = 22477
919                           7517                  ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-5
920        25197   2720                             SEQ: 22477 + 2720 = 25197
923                           8877                  ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-6
924        27917   2720                             SEQ: 25197 + 2720 = 27917
925                           10237                 ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-7
926        30637   2720                             SEQ: 27917 + 2720 = 30637
927                           11597                 ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-8
928        33357   2720                             SEQ: 30637 + 2720 = 33357
930                           12957                 ACK: The ACK to "frame" 865-9
-------    -----------        --------------        -----------------------------
```

For further reading regarding this topic, I'll refer you to an excellent article written by Jasper Bongertz titled, [The drawbacks of local packet captures](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2014/05/the-drawbacks-of-local-packet-captures/).